# Running Gradle Wrapper commands resets Spring application.properties file

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, redis, gradlew

I have added spring.redis.host and spring.redis.port properties to the applications.properties file of my Spring boot application (Apache Fineract) in order to configure it with Redis. However, every time I run any gradle wrapper command, such as ./gradlew clean tomcatRunWar or ./gradlew build, the application.properties file gets reset to the initial version and my edits cannot be seen. 
Is there any way for ensuring that gradle wrapper takes into consideration the custom edits that I am making to it? Thanks.

Comment: By editing the correct one... You are probably editing the one in the build or target directory and not the `src/main/resources` one.

Comment: I am editing the one in the src/main/resources file only. but every time when i run a gradle wrapper command it resets it back to the original application.properties file.

Comment: Then you must be doing strange things in your grade file.

Comment: figured out what the issue was. There were two more properties files, one for basicauth and the other for oauth. Either one of these were being called from the main build.gradle file, depending on how the gradle wrapper commands were being called. thus, the gradle properties had to be set in these two files too.